# Make laptop turn on automatically

Tags: power-supply, power, power-management

I have a laptop of [IBM X41](http://www.notebookreview.com/notebookreview/ibm-thinkpad-x41-review-pics-specs/). I want to use it in a project in making in which it will be used as kiosk.

If power goes out and comes back I have to press the power button to turn the computer back on.

Is the a way to make it automatically turn back on?

Comment: I suspect this might be an option in the BIOS

Comment: I search but didn't find. Is there any other way? Maybe update the bios